# Is there any Listener for Media Recorder?

Tags: android

Actually i am creating an application which starts recording when user start speaking and
stop recording automatically when user stop speaking.

so is there any way to find if user is speaking or not?
is there any listener for Media Recorder for this?

Comment: I am in a same search with this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323452/android-listerner-to-record-sound-if-there-is-any-sound-occurs

Comment: please let me know if you found any sollution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK there are no listeners or intents that would notify your app that sound level has gone above some threshold (e.g. user started talking).

You could use `AudioRecord` class to record the microphone audio and then analyze it to see the volume. However this would require your app to run at that time.

Comment: Hey man! is there any intent that is fire when then sound is being detected by the android microphone ?

Comment: If there is no any listener then i would like to know how that Talking Tom cat app working. Please see this app: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.outfit7.talkingtom&feature=search_result

Comment: Did you even look at my answer?