# Android: Listener to record sound if any sound occurs

Tags: java, android, record, audio, android-mediarecorder

In my application I want to implement methods which record the sound if any sound occurs.

Something similar like this app: [Talking Tom Cat](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.outfit7.talkingtom&feature=search_result)

So what should I have to do?
Is there any demo that listens for sound and records it if any sound occurs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this code in your application...

```
private int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
private int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private byte RECORDER_BPP = (byte) 16;

private AudioRecord audioRecorder;

public void arm() {
    // Get the minimum buffer size required for the successful creation of an AudioRecord object.
    int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

    // Initialize Audio Recorder.
    audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSizeInBytes);

    // Start Recording.
    audioRecorder.startRecording();

    int numberOfReadBytes = 0;
    byte audioBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSizeInBytes];
    boolean recording = false;
    float tempFloatBuffer[] = new float[3];
    int tempIndex = 0;
    int totalReadBytes = 0;
    byte totalByteBuffer[] = new byte[60 * 44100 * 2];

    // While data come from microphone.
    while (true) {
        float totalAbsValue = 0.0f;
        short sample = 0;

        numberOfReadBytes = audioRecorder.read(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);

        // Analyze Sound.
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferSizeInBytes; i += 2) {
            sample = (short) ((audioBuffer[i]) | audioBuffer[i + 1] << 8);
            totalAbsValue += Math.abs(sample) / (numberOfReadBytes / 2);
        }

        // Analyze temp buffer.
        tempFloatBuffer[tempIndex % 3] = totalAbsValue;
        float temp = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            temp += tempFloatBuffer[i];

        if ((temp >= 0 && temp <= 350) && recording == false) {
            Log.i("TAG", "1");
            tempIndex++;
            continue;
        }

        if (temp > 350 && recording == false) {
            Log.i("TAG", "2");
            recording = true;
        }

        if ((temp >= 0 && temp <= 350) && recording == true) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Save audio to file.");

            // Save audio to file.
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath, "AudioRecorder");
            if (!file.exists())
                file.mkdirs();

            String fn = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".wav";

            long totalAudioLen = 0;
            long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
            long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
            int channels = 1;
            long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;
            totalAudioLen = totalReadBytes;
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
            byte finalBuffer[] = new byte[totalReadBytes + 44];

            finalBuffer[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
            finalBuffer[1] = 'I';
            finalBuffer[2] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[3] = 'F';
            finalBuffer[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[8] = 'W';
            finalBuffer[9] = 'A';
            finalBuffer[10] = 'V';
            finalBuffer[11] = 'E';
            finalBuffer[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[13] = 'm';
            finalBuffer[14] = 't';
            finalBuffer[15] = ' ';
            finalBuffer[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
            finalBuffer[17] = 0;
            finalBuffer[18] = 0;
            finalBuffer[19] = 0;
            finalBuffer[20] = 1; // format = 1
            finalBuffer[21] = 0;
            finalBuffer[22] = (byte) channels;
            finalBuffer[23] = 0;
            finalBuffer[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
            finalBuffer[33] = 0;
            finalBuffer[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
            finalBuffer[35] = 0;
            finalBuffer[36] = 'd';
            finalBuffer[37] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[38] = 't';
            finalBuffer[39] = 'a';
            finalBuffer[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            finalBuffer[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

            for (int i = 0; i < totalReadBytes; ++i)
                finalBuffer[44 + i] = totalByteBuffer[i];

            FileOutputStream out;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(fn);
                try {
                    out.write(finalBuffer);
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // */
            tempIndex++;
            break;
        }

        // -> Recording sound here.
        Log.i("TAG", "Recording Sound.");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfReadBytes; i++)
            totalByteBuffer[totalReadBytes + i] = audioBuffer[i];
        totalReadBytes += numberOfReadBytes;
        // */

        tempIndex++;
    }
}
```

**For more details you can also look at this demo...**

http://musicg.googlecode.com/files/musicg_android_demo.zip

Comment: really Nice example. But it only detect whistle. Do you know how to detect normal sound in that case ?

Comment: Deserves more up-votes very helpful. Thank you for spending your time creating this example.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer & anyone else interested - I've modified the code to include missing variables. It works for me but would love that someone else also verifies that it works for them (reedit with your changes if needed)

Comment: @kape123 i am interested to see your changes. Can you please share that?

Comment: @arslanhaktic You are looking at changes - I've changed the code the post you are commenting on.

Comment: Why is temp checked against 350?

Comment: @nikib3ro hello. how can i make this listener work for more time? for example, when i say "one two three" it records only "one"

Answer (score 3):

Please visit the Android developers page about [Audio Capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html).

It has a sample code that demonstrates how to captures and play sounds.

Comment: Please read the title carefully. I have said that i want the demo that listern for the sound and if there is any sound then it will record that sound.

Comment: have you seen that link first ?

Comment: Yes i have seen that link. I dont want to implement the record start on button click. I want is it should be record autometicaly if there is any sound.

Comment: I dont have code but want the code that make device to listern for the any voice occur.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying something similar. From what I have seen you have to start recording before you can read audio levels. So I am trying to measure the amplitude and then increase the length of recording and save the file to a different location if the MaxAmplitude reaches an audible point.

That being said I am VERY new to programming, and would really appreciate any additional tips or tricks.