# How to do Visualizer while recording audio in android

Tags: android, visualizer

I know Visualizer to show some wave while playing audio using android Media Player.

But i want to show Visualizer while recording audio means while recording i want to show linear wave which changes based on user voice beat.

Is it possible to do in android.

Comment: would a level meter be enough, or do you need each frequencies level ?

Comment: i need atleast some beat value to draw a graph my self using graph api

Comment: plot recorded bytes with increasing intervals of time.. refer answer below

Answer (score 19, accepted):

by calling every x milliseconds your MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude(), you gonna have (from [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude%28%29)) :

> the maximum absolute amplitude that was sampled since the last call to
> this method.

then, you can process this value in real time to draw a graph or change some view properties.
not perfect, but I hope it helps =)

**edit:** just so you know, the retrieved value will be the same across all android devices : between 0 and 32767. (I have more than 10k user's reports giving me this value when they blow in the mic).

Comment: it need to specify the output file.. Can it be skipped?

Comment: no it can't, just give the recorder one like this :
File cacheDir = getWritableCacheDir();
samplePath = cacheDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/sample";
mRecorder.setOutputFile(samplePath);

and delete it when you're done...

Comment: @ShashankKumar: or use the AudioRecorder. (no file needed)

Comment: how to use this method with Visualizer class, can you explain in detail or can you provide any sample code which can show all this functionality

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use [AudioRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class instead of MediaRecorder.

Check AudioRecorder#read(...) methods which put audio data to byte[] instead of putting it directly to a file.

To show changes on the graph you will have to analyze the data (which is encoded in PCM 8 or 16 bit - [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#AudioRecord%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)) and update the graph in real time.

Answer (score 3):

Two important things:

- you need to convert live bytes (from mic) to numeric values inorder to plot them.
- Since you use a real-time graph, to plot those points
  use SurfaceView.

  **Convert recording bytes to numeric values** refer:
  [Android: Listener to record sound if any sound occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323452/android-listener-to-record-sound-if-any-sound-occurs) where you will see the variable "temp" holds the numerical value of your audio.

  **Plot points**
  These numeric values which indicates your Y values is plotted against increasing X (time interval) values (0,1,2..)  as graph. Using SurfaceView
  eg..,

> ```
> //canvas.drawLine(previous X value,previous Y value,X,Y, paint);
> canvas.drawPoint(X,Y,paint);
> SurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
> ```

You need not plot all values, for efficiency you can filter those values with your conditions and plot for certain intervals of time.

Hope this helps :)